# Blackberry URL encoder

Tags: java, blackberry, jde

I need to encode a URL using HTTP GET request in Blackberry. Can any one help me find how do I achieve this.

Answer (score 18):

Whyt don't you use RIM's [URLEncodedPostData](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/browser/URLEncodedPostData.html)?

```
private String encodeUrl(String hsURL) {
    URLEncodedPostData urlEncoder = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    urlEncoder.setData(hsURL);
    hsURL = urlEncoder.toString();
    return hsURL;
}
```

Comment: Great solution but not portable. Given he wants to run his software on a different mobile, he'll be asking the same question again. Best is to steer clear of classes which only run on one platform.

Comment: Can't tell for sure... In this case you're right, cause it's not platform dependent functionality. But still simple is good, implement it when they ask you.

Comment: He doesn't actually say he's writing cross-platform mobile code so in this case I'd side with coldice - it seems safer to me (less likely to introduce bugs) to use a native API over a homebrew approach.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding the question here, but I don't think this answer does what the question asks, at all.  `URLEncodedPostData` is meant for URL encoding sets of **POST** params (key/value pairs), to be written as content bytes in a `POST` request.  It looks to me (and to a couple other answers here) that the OP is asking to encode the URL itself.  For example, `http://maps.google.com/?addr=123 Main St, New York, NY` -> `http://maps.google.com/?addr=123+Main+St,+New+York,+NY`. This doesn't do that.

Comment: I am not able to get a proper URL encoded string from this solution : here is my link https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=HD5&DT4 8TA

Answer (score 8):

here you go  ;^)

```
public static String URLencode(String s)
{
    if (s!=null) {
        StringBuffer tmp = new StringBuffer();
        int i=0;
        try {
            while (true) {
                int b = (int)s.charAt(i++);
                if ((b>=0x30 && b<=0x39) || (b>=0x41 && b<=0x5A) || (b>=0x61 && b<=0x7A)) {
                    tmp.append((char)b);
                }
                else {
                    tmp.append("%");
                    if (b <= 0xf) tmp.append("0");
                    tmp.append(Integer.toHexString(b));
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {}
        return tmp.toString();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

use the class provided by w3. Here is the download [link](http://www.w3.org/International/URLUTF8Encoder.java)

Answer (score 3):

[the reply using "URLEncodedPostData" above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1211419/119114) is incorrect.
Corrected sample:

```
public static String encodeUrl(Hashtable params)
{
    URLEncodedPostData urlEncoder = new URLEncodedPostData("UTF-8", false);
    Enumeration keys = params.keys();
    while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
        String name = (String) keys.nextElement();
        String value = (String) params.get(name);
        urlEncoder.append(name, value);
    }

    String encoded = urlEncoder.toString();
    return encoded;
}
```

Cheers!