# How to remove spaces from blackberry URL

Tags: java, blackberry, whitespace

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Blackberry URL encoder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211299/blackberry-url-encoder)

i am using

```
    String url="http://xxxxxx.com/api/api.php?func=xxxxxxxxxxxx&params[]="+searchText+CustomUtility.getConnectionString();

    HttpConnection conn=(HttpConnection)Connector.open(url);
    InputStream in=(InputStream)conn.openInputStream();
    SAXParserFactory factory=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser parser=factory.newSAXParser();
    parser.parse(in, new ContactParser());
```

problem  is this when searchText has many spaces it is not working , so please how i can remove spaces from URL

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/724043/http-url-address-encoding-in-java.

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
URLUTF8Encoder.enceode(searchText);
```

URLUTF8Encoder class is given below-

```
public class URLUTF8Encoder {

 final static String[] hex = {
"%00", "%01", "%02", "%03", "%04", "%05", "%06", "%07",
"%08", "%09", "%0A", "%0B", "%0C", "%0D", "%0E", "%0F",
"%10", "%11", "%12", "%13", "%14", "%15", "%16", "%17",
"%18", "%19", "%1A", "%1B", "%1C", "%1D", "%1E", "%1F",
"%20", "%21", "%22", "%23", "%24", "%25", "%26", "%27",
"%28", "%29", "%2A", "%2B", "%2C", "%2D", "%2E", "%2F",
"%30", "%31", "%32", "%33", "%34", "%35", "%36", "%37",
"%38", "%39", "%3A", "%3B", "%3C", "%3D", "%3E", "%3F",
"%40", "%41", "%42", "%43", "%44", "%45", "%46", "%47",
"%48", "%49", "%4A", "%4B", "%4C", "%4D", "%4E", "%4F",
"%50", "%51", "%52", "%53", "%54", "%55", "%56", "%57",
"%58", "%59", "%5A", "%5B", "%5C", "%5D", "%5E", "%5F",
"%60", "%61", "%62", "%63", "%64", "%65", "%66", "%67",
"%68", "%69", "%6A", "%6B", "%6C", "%6D", "%6E", "%6F",
"%70", "%71", "%72", "%73", "%74", "%75", "%76", "%77",
"%78", "%79", "%7A", "%7B", "%7C", "%7D", "%7E", "%7F",
"%80", "%81", "%82", "%83", "%84", "%85", "%86", "%87",
"%88", "%89", "%8A", "%8B", "%8C", "%8D", "%8E", "%8F",
"%90", "%91", "%92", "%93", "%94", "%95", "%96", "%97",
"%98", "%99", "%9A", "%9B", "%9C", "%9D", "%9E", "%9F",
"%A0", "%A1", "%A2", "%A3", "%A4", "%A5", "%A6", "%A7",
"%A8", "%A9", "%AA", "%AB", "%AC", "%AD", "%AE", "%AF",
"%B0", "%B1", "%B2", "%B3", "%B4", "%B5", "%B6", "%B7",
"%B8", "%B9", "%BA", "%BB", "%BC", "%BD", "%BE", "%BF",
"%C0", "%C1", "%C2", "%C3", "%C4", "%C5", "%C6", "%C7",
"%C8", "%C9", "%CA", "%CB", "%CC", "%CD", "%CE", "%CF",
"%D0", "%D1", "%D2", "%D3", "%D4", "%D5", "%D6", "%D7",
"%D8", "%D9", "%DA", "%DB", "%DC", "%DD", "%DE", "%DF",
"%E0", "%E1", "%E2", "%E3", "%E4", "%E5", "%E6", "%E7",
"%E8", "%E9", "%EA", "%EB", "%EC", "%ED", "%EE", "%EF",
"%F0", "%F1", "%F2", "%F3", "%F4", "%F5", "%F6", "%F7",
"%F8", "%F9", "%FA", "%FB", "%FC", "%FD", "%FE", "%FF"
};
 public static String encode(String s)
 {   
 StringBuffer sbuf = new StringBuffer();
 int len = s.length();
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  int ch = s.charAt(i);
  if ('A' <= ch && ch <= 'Z') {     // 'A'..'Z'
    sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if ('a' <= ch && ch <= 'z') {  // 'a'..'z'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if ('0' <= ch && ch <= '9') {  // '0'..'9'
       sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if (ch == ' ') {           // space
       //sbuf.append('+');
       sbuf.append("%20");
  } else if (ch == '!') {
      sbuf.append("%21");
  } else if (ch == '*') {
      sbuf.append("%2A");
  } else if (ch == '(') {
      sbuf.append("%28");
  } else if (ch == ')') {
      sbuf.append("%29");
  } else if (ch == '\'') {
      sbuf.append("%27");   
  } else if (ch == '-' || ch == '_'     // unreserved
      || ch == '.'
      || ch == '~' || ch == '\'')  {
    sbuf.append((char)ch);
  } else if (ch <= 0x007f) {        // other ASCII
       sbuf.append(hex[ch]);
  } else if (ch <= 0x07FF) {        // non-ASCII <= 0x7FF
       sbuf.append(hex[0xc0 | (ch >> 6)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)]);
  } else {                  // 0x7FF < ch <= 0xFFFF
       sbuf.append(hex[0xe0 | (ch >> 12)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | ((ch >> 6) & 0x3F)]);
       sbuf.append(hex[0x80 | (ch & 0x3F)]);
  }
}
return sbuf.toString();
}
}
```

Comment: Stack over flow is my best friend

Answer (score -1):

you can use the below code to remove white space character in a given string ,you can call this method like this:

```
replace("PassyourString" , "   " , "");
```

---

```
public static String replace(String s, String f, String r) {
    if (s == null) {
        return s;
    }
    if (f == null) {
        return s;
    }
    if (r == null) {
        r = "";
    }
    int index01 = s.indexOf(f);
    while (index01 != -1) {
        s = s.substring(0, index01) + r + s.substring(index01 + f.length());
        index01 += r.length();
        index01 = s.indexOf(f, index01);
    }
    return s;
}
```